# Set image as window background Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I understand how to get an image into tkinter with `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Image"))`, but is it possible to set that image as the background of a window? I know that you can set it as a label then pack it into the window, but can you actually just set it as the background for the window?

I tried to use the `bg` argument of `root.config()`, but it just came up with the error `_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "pyimage1"`, from which I deduced that that was not the way to go about it.

Comment: Tkinter widgets have no concept of a background image - a solid color is all that is supported.  Only a few widget types (primarily Label and Canvas) can display an image on top of that background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the root window and instances of `Toplevel` do not support a background image. It’s trivial to create a label with an image, and configure it to cover the entire window. You can then put all other widgets inside the label.